# How to invert dependencies in react-json-schema-form

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

The question is regarding to react-jsonschema-form
https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form

The following schema dependencies define that if inputA has any value inputB gets required and vice versa. (Bidirectional dependency)

How can I archive that inputA isn't mandatory if inputB is filled and vice versa.
There is no "NOT" operator available.

```
{
  type: 'object',
  title: 'Inverted Dependencies',
  dependencies: {
    inputA: ['inputB'],
    inputB: ['inputA'],
  },
  properties: {
    inputA: { type: 'string'},
    inputB: { type: 'string'},
  }
}
```